# SQL Cluster instance does not see all drives

Tags: sql-server-2014

As DBA on SQL 2014 FCI, I need to do a local backup. However, I do not see all drives available on the VM . I only see the drives added as storage disks in the FCI UI.
in order to see the other drives in the backup menu, do I need to add it to storage disks in FCI?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is the whole purpose of FCI. You will only see the disk part of shared storage in that cluster.

I am not sure what you are trying to exactly do when you say local backup. Backup of database ? If yes then I guess that should be simple enough to backup in the drive part of shared storage so that after failover to other node backup continues to work.

There are few drives which we might not care local installation directories to be part of same shared storage or software drives or dba script drives what we have in our env.
So totally depends what drives are you talking about here

Comment: Hi Kasqldba, my question is if in order to see the drive ( for ex: in the instance properties or in the backup menu), I can only see the shared storage disks from FCI correct? And in order to see another drive in the failover instance properties, I need to add to shared storage, correct?

Comment: Correct that’s what I meant other way around

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your reply. My questions are if in order to see the drive ( for ex: in the instance properties or in the backup menu), I can only see the shared storage disks from FCI, correct? And in order to see another drive in the instance properties (for this failover cluster instance), I need to add to shared storage, correct?